# Distinct list<string> of chars

Tags: c#, linq, list, distinct

I have this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("a-b-c>d");
list.Add("b>c");
list.Add("f>e");
list.Add("f>e-h");
list.Add("a-d>c-b");
```

I want to delete duplicates. In this case duplicates are "a-b-c>d" and "a-d>c-b". Both have same chars but in diferente order.
I tried with:

```
list.Distinct().ToList();
```

But didn't work!

Comment: both are different strings. It is not duplicate.

Comment: @user, you actually think pear and reap are the same words?

Comment: no other way , go char by char check

Comment: What you're looking to do in fact is remove equivalents based on an arbitrary equivalence rule, not duplicates. But how would you even decide which "equivalent" is to be removed - by your logic "ABC" and "BAC" are the same, right? So which one "wins"?

Comment: The first wins! I tried also `if (list[j].All(c => list[k].Contains(c)) && list[j].Length == list[k].Length)  list.RemoveAt(j)` but I have problem in a long chain (> 80 chars)

Comment: I forgot to explain some list values has different string lenght!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
var distinct = list
    .Select((str, idx) => new { Str = str, Idx = idx })
    .GroupBy(pair => new HashSet<char>(pair.Str), HashSet<char>.CreateSetComparer())
    .Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(p => p.Idx).First())
    .ToList();
```

This will keep the first element and remove any later strings in the sequence which contains the same characters.

You can also use `Aggregate` to track the character sets you've already seen:

```
var distinct = list
    .Aggregate(new Dictionary<HashSet<char>, string>(HashSet<char>.CreateSetComparer()), (dict, str) =>
    {
        var set = new HashSet<char>(str);
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(set))
            dict.Add(set, str);
        return dict;
    })
    .Values
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Assuming the number of `-` and `>` need to match as well, this is great.

Comment: How to convert distinct in List<string>. I tried to cast but no cash!

Comment: @user1801745 - Just call `ToList` on the resulting sequence, I've update the code.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin - Yes, I thought after re-reading the question that all duplicates should be removed but reading the comments it looks like the first one should be kept.

Comment: I have other listDistance<double> and need to delete the same index of these duplicates... how?

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to define a custom `IEqualityComparer` that allows the system to understand when you consider two strings to be "equal". For example:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("a-b-c>d");
list.Add("b>c-d-f");
list.Add("c-d-f>e");
list.Add("a-d>c-b");
var distinctItems = list.Distinct(new KeyFuncEqualityComparer<string>(
    s => new String(s.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(c => c).ToArray())));
```

Result:

```
a-b-c>d 
b>c-d-f 
c-d-f>e
```

... using this generic IEqualityComparer implementation:

```
public class KeyFuncEqualityComparer<T> :IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, object> _getKey;

    public KeyFuncEqualityComparer(Func<T, object> getKey)
    {
        _getKey = getKey;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return _getKey(x).Equals(_getKey(y));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return _getKey(obj).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

untested

```
    list<int> dups = new list<int>();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.count - 1; i++)
    {
         for(int j = 1; j < list.count; j++)
         {
                int len = list[j].length;
             bool b = false;
           for(int k = 0; k < list[i].length; k++)
            {
                if(k < len && (list[i][k] != list[j][k]))
               {
                b = false;
                break;
            }
         b = true;
     }
    if(b == true)
    {
    dups.add(i);
     }
    }
    }
```

then remove all dups from list

Comment: Ack, my eyes! What language is that? What's the cyclomatic complexity?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior and the key part - it's untested

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - haha i like it, basically loop through and if you get a match, add it to a list, then remove these from the list :P

Comment: @Sayse Yes, and that's a particularly inefficient algorithm for solving this problem, particularly when compared to the other answers that are much better.

Comment: Yeah, I'm probably going to have to downvote this one. I hate downvoting, but this just needs to go away.

Comment: @Servy - obviously took me a while  to write it, and then it took so long so figured i'd post anyway

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Why did you delete your answer?  It, unlike Lee's, returns the original strings in the result rather than the strings that have been re-ordered.

Comment: @Servy: I liked that his answer didn't require a custom class, and for a moment, he had it working right. Then he changed it. I'll go ahead and keep my answer up for those who are interested.